# WCF message doesn't go through protocol verification

Tags: wcf, soap, service, trace

I am writing WCF service that should process SOAP message from external client (which I have no influence to and very basic support). It is hosted on IIS and communicates over https.

When message is sent from client, service is not working. I am getting error message in trace logs that seems to be related to refusal of client to receive response message. It looks like WCF is trying to send failure message with "POST" action which client don't support.
In the other hand, when the same message is sent by Postman, it is processed perfectly!

What I noticed in trace logs is that when message is processed (sent by Postman), in "Process action ..." activity, after event "Received a message over a channel" I have trace event **"The security protocol verified the incoming message"**. After that, processing is going its proper way and proper response is sent back.
[Verification succeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW6o2.png)

When external client send that message this, in "Process action ..." activity final event is "Received a message over a channel". There is no error or warning that security protocol failed to verify the incoming message or something like that but that message never reach service contract.
[No verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9gNA.png)

It would appreciate very much if someone can help me to make seance of this and point me in the right direction as I am starting to lose my hair over this.

- EDIT
  If this can help, here is activity graph:[Activity Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/039hS.png)

Comment: Thank you for beautification of my question. It is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the wrong track all the time. Should follow exactly what was the message of exception I was receiving. The real problem was that, although client provider is claiming usage of SOAP 1.2 with WS-Addressing, along with proper action name in SOAP message header, they are sending **different** action in HTTP header (which is legacy from SOAP 1.1)! When they match those two everything went smoothly.

You think they should knew that, especially considering company significance and size, but no. Until I found exact problem they haven't considered this as a problem.

I hope this can help others running similar problem in the future.

Answer (score -1):

From your description, you can call the service by `PostMan`, while cannot invoke the service by the particular client-side, is that right?
WCF usually works with SOAP web service style, which means that it only accepts an invocation from a client proxy rather than a direct HTTP request from `PostMan`.
Please post your complete error that occurred on the client-side. I think it might relate to the type of external clients, which determined which type of WCF service should be established.
Besides, if the WCF works over HTTPS, we should establish the trust relationship first on the client-side before sending a request.
Feel free to let me know if there anything I can help with.

Comment: I have no real knowledge what was reported on the client side. They are just reporting that there is no response from my service. Exception that I am getting is `The SOAP action specified on the message, 'ReceiveMessageSync', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'POST'. `. It looks like that my service (actually WCF, because it seems my code was never reached) is trying to send response back and client is rejecting it.

Comment: SOAP messages can be sent using Postman just fine. All SOAP is is a particular XML format sent along with custom headers in an HTTP request, and that's exactly what Postman can do. It's not like the C# classes you generate a proxy with add some magic, it's just that it makes it easier to call a SOAP service. You can do the same using an HttpClient in .NET.

Comment: I am aware of what you are saying. I just can't locate what goes wrong when message is received. When I send it by Postman, I can see that it is verified by transport protocol. When client sends it, there is no verification message but no error in verification either and that is what bothers me.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I  knew that. Would you mind sharing a successful HTTP request? that calls a WCF service with Transport security mode(WS*-Binding) using windows authentication. It seems to me that you can call this type of service easily by using Postman. I am glad to see a example provided by you. besides Wshttpbinding,  I think you are very familiar with the authentication mechanism. I would like to know how you can achieve that in PostMan. very thanks.

Comment: @zoranmiškov  , The client may send the request as a proxy object instead of sending the HTTP request directly. it means that the request attaches authentication mode information and so on.  What authentication credentials does it use? If it is a problem of negotiation of a specific TLS version, we need to install a server certificate on the client and specify the `TLS` version. From the information you provided, I can't guess more about the client. As far as you know, how is the client structured, or what kind of service has it normally communicated with?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Service uses custom binding because I needed `messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"`. Security is `authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"`. Client is using TLS 1.2. so I have compiled the project with dot.net 4.8. It is sending direct HTTP request, straightforward SOAP XML with 1.2 envelope, WS-Addressing and WS-Security. Server has a valid certificate (from Go Daddy I believe).